How to change the labels of a pretrained hugging face model?
I am using below pretrained hugging face model for sentiment analysis:
"cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment-latest"
And it's providing three sentiments - Positive, Negative and Neutral
Now I want to adapt this model for my use case which should classify the sentiment as - satisfied, positive, frustrated and confused.
So, How can we achieve this particular task. Would be very helpful if any code provided for the same.
def classify_sentiment(text):
    MODEL = f"cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment-latest"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(MODEL)

    model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)
    # text = preprocess_text(text)
    encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
    output = model(**encoded_input)
    scores = output[0][0].detach().numpy()
    scores = softmax(scores)
    ranking = np.argsort(scores)
    ranking = ranking[::-1]

    results = {}
    for i in range(scores.shape[0]):
        l = config.id2label[ranking[i]]
        s = scores[ranking[i]]
        results[l] = np.round(float(s), 4)

    return results


How much training data, with your four labels, have you got? And do you have to start with that particular model?

@DarrenCook can you share how to fine tune model this link?
